# Global variables mixed with other servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently making a snipe command into my Discord Bot. But, when I snipe the message on server 1 (example), and I do the command on another server, it would still say the sniped message on server 1. How can I prevent this from happening? I want it to not be mixing between channels.

Code:

```
class utility(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.snipe_message_content = None
        self.snipe_message_author = None
        self.snipe_message_id = None

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        self.snipe_message_content = message.content
        self.snipe_message_author = message.author.id
        self.snipe_message_id = message.id
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if message.id == self.snipe_message_id:
            self.snipe_message_author = None
            self.snipe_message_content = None
            self.snipe_message_id = None

    @commands.command()
    async def snipe(self, message):
        if self.snipe_message_content==None:
            await message.channel.send("It seems like there are nothing to snipe with!")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{self.snipe_message_content}", colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_author(name= f"<@{self.snipe_message_author}>")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a dict

Something like this:

```py
class utility(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.sniped_messages = {}

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        server_id = message.guild.id
        self.sniped_messages[server_id] = {"content": message.content,
                                           "author": message.author.id}
        # * OR USE A TUPLE *
        # self.sniped_messages[server_id] = (message.content, message.author.id)

        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if message.id == self.sniped_messages[server_id]["id"]:
            self.sniped_messages.pop(server_id)

    @commands.command()
    async def snipe(self, message):
        if message.guild.id not in self.sniped_messages:
            await message.channel.send("It seems like there are nothing to snipe with!")
        else:
            sniped_message = self.sniped_messages[message.guild.id]
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{sniped_message['content']}", colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_author(name= f"<@{sniped_message['author']}>")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

Please tell me if there are any error, hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The cog right now has one variable for the snipped messages. So if you run the command on another server, all it will do is check that one variable.
Instead, you should keep a dictionary, so that the keys would be the servers, and the values would be the snipped messages.

When changing this, every time you check the snipped message, you'll first want to get the id of the server and fetch the message from the dictionary that way. And when you want to store it, you'll want to fetch the id of the server to insert it to the dictionary under that key.